# The catch_error_yn function is not working

Tags: python

I can't figure out how to make the catch_error_yn work. Can someone explain why the function does not work and how to fix it?

```
def catch_error_yn():
    unvalid = True
    while unvalid:
        try:
            response = "Yes" 
            response = "No"
            unvalid = False
            return response
        except ValueError:
            print("please only enter 'Yes' or 'No' with capitals on Y or N:")

def carpark():
    print("Do you want a free parking space, please answer 'Yes' or 'No' with capital letters on Y or N")
    response = catch_error_yn
    print(response)

print("Welcome to Copington Adventure Theme Park's automated ticket system\nplease press any button to see the ticket prices.")
enter = input()
print("\nAdult tickets are £20 each \nChild tickets are £12 each \nSenior citizen tickets are £11 each")
carpark()
```

Comment: You didn't ***call*** the function: `response = catch_error_yn()`

Answer (score 0):

When you call your function, you have to add empty parentheses. I also fixed the `catch_error_yn()` function, based on what I think is the intended purpose. Here is the corrected code:

```
def catch_error_yn():
    while True:
        userR = input("Do you want a free parking space, please answer 'Yes' or 'No' with capital letters on Y or N\n")
        if userR == "Y":
            return "Yes"
        elif userR == "N":
            return "No"
        else:
            print("Invalid Answer")
        

def carpark():
    response = catch_error_yn()
    print(response)

enter = input("Welcome to Copington Adventure Theme Park's automated ticket system\nplease press any button to see the ticket prices.\n")
print("\nAdult tickets are £20 each \nChild tickets are £12 each \nSenior citizen tickets are £11 each")
carpark()
```

Comment: It worked for me. The program always returns "No" though. Is that the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a small bug in the code, in that, you are not passing the `input()` to the `catch_error_yn()` function.

I am making some assumptions about the intent of your code, and adding the modified working code here :

```
def catch_error_yn():
    unvalid = True
    while unvalid:
        try:
            #get input inside the function
            response = input()
            # check if it is valid if, not raise an error
            if response not in ['Y', 'N'] :
                raise ValueError()
            return response
        except ValueError:
            print("please only enter 'Yes' or 'No' with capitals on Y or N:")

def carpark():
    print("Do you want a free parking space, please answer 'Yes' or 'No' with capital letters on Y or N")
    response = catch_error_yn()
    print(response)

print("Welcome to Copington Adventure Theme Park's automated ticket system\nplease press any button to see the ticket prices.")
print("\nAdult tickets are £20 each \nChild tickets are £12 each \nSenior citizen tickets are £11 each")
carpark()
```

Comment: Hi, i tried this and it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I edited it slightly and it's working now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: glad to know, it helped.